# Docker container mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk publish not as a root user

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core

I use a docker container to build C# appliaction.

The problem is that permission of the output files and dir (/bin and /obj) is "root"

I want the output of files not to be as a root user (I know the command chown but I want to get the files not as a root).

Example:
`docker run --rm -v /home/user/d:/app -w /app mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 dotnet publish`

Answer (score 1):

With the default `dotnet/sdk` this is not possible. But you can build your own container image and use it for building the application:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1

ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

RUN groupadd -g $GID user
RUN useradd -g $GID -u $UID -m -s /bin/bash user
USER user
WORKDIR /app
```

Build it with your `uid` and `gid` like this:

```
docker build <path to dir with Dockerfile> --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) -t buildcontainer
```

This will build the image with a user `user` that has the same uid and gid as your current user. You can then use the image instead of `dotnet/sdk` to build the application:

```
docker run --rm -v /home/user/d:/app buildcontainer dotnet publish
```

Because uid and gid match between container and your environment outside the container, the output files will have the ownership that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build  
RUN  mkdir ./app 
RUN  chmod 777 ./app 
WORKDIR  /app  
COPY . . 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o dist nameapp.csproj   

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 as runtime
COPY --from=build app/dist dist

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dist/nameapp.dll"]
```

Here is an example Dockerfile in case it helps you.